# Firefox onkeypress event not passing in event parameter

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom-events, onkeypress

I have the following textarea HTML tag that I am inserting a runtime into the DOM (I have only shown how it looks after it is inserted) and I'm set the `onkeypress` event to fire as an inline attribute.  However, in Firefox I get an "event is not defined" error when I press a key went it is in focus.

```
<textarea rows="3" cols="70" type="text" name="resultsRename" value="" class="redlining_textContent_Dialog_textbox" dojoType="dijit.forms.SimpleTextArea" id="labelText" propercase="false" style="width:auto;" onkeypress="return handleEnterKey(event,doFunc();">

function handleEnterKey(e, func)
{
    //alert("hit key handler");
    //alert(dojo.toJson(e));
    var key = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if (key == 13)
    {
        func();
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }

}
```

I have looked at tons of help telling me that I should expect an event object parameter to be available to the js code I place in the `onkeypress` attr, but I keep getting this error.

The textarea tag is not inside a pair of form tags (I saw somewhere that this can be an issue sometimes but I have no choice here).

I have tried a `handleEnterKey` function with only the `e` parameter but this makes no difference.

If I change the inline attribute to...

```
onkeypress="return handleEnterKey(this,doFunc();"
```

... I enter the `handleEnterKe`y with my `e` parameter set to the textarea object. Why Am I not being passed the event object?  Obviously this works fine in IE with it's global event object.

At my wits end. Help me Stack Overflow... you're my only hope!

Answer (score 4):

`handleEnterKey` should not even be called as you have a syntax error.

```
return handleEnterKey(event,doFunc();
```

should be

```
return handleEnterKey(event,doFunc);
```

Passing `event` definitely works: [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/K3Pw9/)